# Visual Studio: required dll/pdb files not copied to correct directory

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using visual studio 2015 and I have a solution with a series of .net projects that include one another. The structire is this:

Project `Test` (application) includes `library project A`
`library project A` includes `library project B`

The flow of execution is as follows:

`Test` calls a method in `A` that calls a method in `B`

Now, this compiles correctly, however if I run/debug project `Test` only the `library project A` DLL/PDB files are copied to `project Test`'s `/bin/debug` directory before launching, but not the DLL/PDB of `library project B`. This results in the project crashing and in me not being able to debug it.

I know I can add post-build commands to manually copy the files over, but shouldn't visual studio be doing it on its own, since the projects include each other? Why isn't it doing it? It does for every other project I've ever developed, but now it just stopped... did I accidentally change some option? Where should I look?

Comment: How did you add the references in your Test project? Did you add a "Project" reference or did you browse directly to the compile .dll file of `library project A`?

Comment: @MauritsvanBeusekom: that's the first thing I thought of, but I checked and they were all project references. I solved it tho, see my answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I created a new solution and re-added all projects one by one. Now it's working again. Weird, VS must have screwed up in some manner.